# VS2012 Update 4 with Web Tools 2013.1 MVC5 Razor Still Not Syntax Highlighting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

After doing all the steps I can find I'm still not seeing any syntax highlighting.  I've gone through every check and post I can find on the subject and as far as I can tell I've done everything suggested.

I've updated my root web.config with:

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
```

I've checked all other settings in relation to web.config files in any `Views` directories.  I already had VS2012 Update 4 installed and I've installed VS 2012 with ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1.41108 update from here:

http://www.asp.net/downloads

I've removed the MVC4 Project Type GUID from the project file and still no highlighting.  This as far as I can tell is everything that needs doing to get this working.

Is there anything else I should try?  Is there no project type GUID for MVC 5?  Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a lot of messing around and trying lots of different solutions including:

- Uninstalling Xamarin
- Delete all .suo files

I have gotten it to work by changing these settings:

- In VS got to Tools -> options
- select Text Editor\All Languages
- Check Auto List Members
- Check Advanced Members
- Check Parameter information
- Do the same for C#

Bingo, Razor Syntax highlighting start working without a VS restart (at least for me).